# How to search for column existence in Hive table

Tags: hive

hive table that has around 50 columns. Finding out a specific using Describe command or running select command is becoming tedious.

Is there a way we can search for existence of column in Hive table?

And also, can we use substring in the column name instead of complete name that will much more useful.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can query the Hive metastore.  How that works will depend on what Hadoop stack you have, and what DB the metastore uses.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no command to check this directly ,but you have below options.

```
1) Query column name , if you get NOT FOUND exception , the column doesn't exist.
2) Describe first , iterate through results and search for the column you are looking for.
3) Use Hive meta store client and get HiveMetastoreClient.getFields ,this will give list of columns ,iterate and search for your column
```